# On the degree of $F(ab)$ if degrees of $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are relatively primes

Tags: field-theory

Let $a,b$ be two algebraic elements over $F$. Suppose $[F(a):F]=m$ and $[F(b):F]=n$, with $m,n$ relatively prime. I think $[F(ab):F]=mn$, but I don't know how to prove it (I have $[F(ab):F]\leq mn$).

Any hint to prove the another inequality?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $F(a,b)$ instead of $F(ab)$?

Comment: No, it's not. It's $F(ab)$.

Comment: We can just take $a=0$ and $b$ be any element not in $F$ as a trivial counterexample :D. But this is surely not as illuminating as the example Ihf gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim is false.

Let $F=\mathbb Q$.

Let $a$ be a root of $x^2+x+1$, so that $a$ is a primitive cubic root of unity.

Let $b=\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Then $[F(a):F]=2$ and $[F(b):F]=3$ but $[F(ab):F]=3$, not $6$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $[F(ab):F]$ **divides** $nm$. Indeed, we have that $[F(a,b):F]=nm$, since
$$\begin{align*}
[F(a,b):F]&=[F(a,b):F(a)][F(a):F] = m[F(a,b):F(a)]\\
&\leq m[F(b):F] = mn,\\
[F(a,b):F]&=[F(a,b):F(b)][F(b):F] = n[F(a,b):F(b)]\\
&\leq n[F(a):F] = mn.
\end{align*}$$
So $n$ and $m$ both divide $[F(a,b):F]$, and since $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then $nm$ divides $[F(a,b):F]$.  Since $[F(a,b):F]\leq nm$, and is a multiple of $nm$, then $[F(a,b):F]=nm$.

Now we have that $ab\in F(a,b)$, hence $nm=[F(a,b):F] = [F(a,b):F(ab)][F(ab):F]$,
so $[F(ab):F]$ divides $nm$. But it need not be equal, as  lhf's example shows.